# Fixing vector issue - Finding middle element of vector - C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code an efficient method to which :

`The maximum number of list values for any test case should not exceed 9. If exceeded, output "Too many numbers".`

I have the solution down for finding the middle number in a vector, but can't figure out a way to detect if the values received are more than 9.

Obviously the vector will never be more than 9 since the vector gets resized in the loop and was wondering if anyone could guide me through a work around! Thank you in advance!

Task description:

> Given a sorted list of integers, output the middle integer. A negative number indicates the end of the input (the negative number is not a part of the sorted list). Assume the number of integers is always odd.
>
> The maximum number of list values for any test case should not exceed 9. If exceeded, output "Too many numbers".

> Input: 2 3 4 8 11 -1

> Output: Middle item: 4

> Input: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 -1

> Output: Too many numbers

when input:

> 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 -1

is used, my output is:

> Middle item: 50

instead of

> Too many numbers

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>   // Must include vector library to use vectors
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int NUM = 9;
   vector<int> numInts(NUM);
   int value;
   
   //fills loop in with values    
   for ( int i = 0; i < numInts.size(); ++i){
   cin >> value;
     if (value > 0){
     numInts.at(i) = value;
     
     }
     else{
     numInts.resize(i);
     break;
     }
   }
  
   //outputs vector if within size -- but will always be in size(need to fix)
   if (numInts.size() > 9){
   cout << "Too many numbers" << endl;
   }
   else{
   cout << "Middle item: " << numInts.at(numInts.size()/2) << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you read 10 numbers and none of them are negative, there are too many numbers.

Comment: `i < numInts.size()` won't work. `std::vector` will expand as necessary. Instead `const int nelem = 9;` and then test `numints.size() < nelem`. (`nelem` short for number of elements)

Comment: I don't think I'm quite understanding what your saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reimplement your code so it will work as you want.
Ask me if you feel that this code doesn't seems right to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums(10);
    int value=0;
    int numberOfElements=0;
    bool moreThanNine=false;
    while(cin>>value)
    {
        if(value==-1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfElements++;
            if(numberOfElements>9)
            {
                moreThanNine=true;
            }
            else
            {
                nums.at(numberOfElements-1) = value;
            }
        }
    }
    if(moreThanNine)
    {
        cout << "Too many numbers" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Middle item: " << nums.at(numberOfElements/2) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```